# psycopg2 fails on execute many statement with syntax error

Tags: python, mongodb, psycopg2

I have data coming from `mongodb` which looks like

```
data = 
(
 {
   u'name': 'A',
   u'primary_key': 1
 },
 {
   u'name': 'B',
   u'primary_key': 2
 },
 {
   u'name': 'C',
   u'primary_key': 3
 }
)
```

when I call the following

```
cur = conn.cursor()
cur.executemany("""INSERT INTO ddmension(id,name) VALUES (%(primary_key)s, %(name)s)""", data)
```

it fails saying

```
ProgrammingError: 'syntax error at or near """"INSERT INTO dimension (id, name) VALUES (1, E\'A\')""""\nLINE 1: """INSERT INTO dimension (id, name) VALUES (1, E\'A\n ^\n'
```

Can someone guide me what the issue could be? I am following [this](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Psycopg2_Tutorial) tutorial

Thank you

Comment: the fact that there is a typo in the table name means that you didn't post the exact code and/or output that you get.

Comment: What `cur.mogrify(args_to_executemany)` shows?

Answer (score 0):

We should try un-quoting that error message to see a bit more clearly what is going on here. We can do that at the Python prompt:

```
>>> message = 'syntax error at or near """"INSERT INTO dimension (id, name) VALUES (1, E\'A\')""""\nLINE 1: """INSERT INTO dimension (id, name) VALUES (1, E\'A\n ^\n'
>>> print message
syntax error at or near """"INSERT INTO dimension (id, name) VALUES (1, E'A')""""
LINE 1: """INSERT INTO dimension (id, name) VALUES (1, E'A
 ^
```

Ahh, much better.

Normally, Postgres is careful to use the little `^` character to point at the exact place in the line where it got confused — but here, it is pointing at the middle of the “Line 1” label that it puts in *front* of the line that confused it. Probably your cut-and-paste into Stack Overflow collapsed several consecutive spaces together, which can happen if your editor or browser were in a disagreeable mood.

So I cannot tell exactly where in the line the error occurred, but I have a very strong guess: somehow, the Python triple-quotes with which you are trying to surround your statement are actually getting passed in to Postgres! After several minutes of playing around at the Postgres prompt, the *only* way I can find to get a “syntax error” message whose ”LINE” starts with triple quotes is to actually type the triple quotes manually into the SQL, where they do not belong (since Postgres does not understand triple-quoting; it's a Python convention):

```
$ psql postgres 
Null display is "NULL".
psql (8.4.8)
Type "help" for help.

postgres=# """SELECT 1""";
ERROR:  syntax error at or near """"SELECT 1""""
LINE 1: """SELECT 1""";
        ^
```

The problem is that this error is impossible with the sample code that you have displayed. To get this error, you would have had to in fact type Python code like this:

```
cur.executemany('"""INSERT INTO ddmension(id,name) ..."""', data)
```

There are other ways to get triple-quotes inside of a Python string, but this is the easiest. In any case, your Postgres error message is most certainly showing that triple quotes are getting inside of your SQL, so try checking your Python code again, and we will help you figure out how literal quote marks are winding up inside your strings!