# how to write a json file in python without using dumps

Tags: python, json, dataframe, pyspark, bson

I have the following bson data from MongoDB. I have to convert the code in to valid json for creating a PySpark DataFrame.

```
"\"{u'_raja': ObjectId('XXXXXX'),\\n u'ram': datetime.datetime(XXx,xx14, xx, xx, xxx),\\n u'createUserId': u'praja-policy',\\n u'raja': u'I5',\\n u'udatedTime': datetime.datetime(XXx, xx, xx, xx, xx, xx, xxxx),\\n u'lastupdatedid': u'raja_id',\\n u'plt': u'123r32'}\""
```

I have written the following code.

```
from bson import json_util
with open("/XXXXX6/bi/XXXXX/XXXXX3/v0/test/bson.json", "rb") as f:
bson = f.read()
data= bson.replace('u\'','') – removal of Unicode 
data1 = data.replace('\n','') – removal of \n
json.dump(json_util.dumps(data), open("bson1.json", "w"))
```

using **json.dump** is giving me the valid json but, with the format "\".

How to extract the values inside the unicode? So, that I can crate a PySpark DataFrame.

Comment: how to remove the unicode u-character  .using python2.7 .

Comment: Do you want to extract string inside u'string'?

Comment: @prazy i want to remove the unicode characters and make my json as a valid json to create a dataframe

Comment: Why does the data exist in this format in the first place? If you control the string creation, you should be addressing the problem there

Comment: I feel this is from mongoDB.

Comment: @Prazy yes this data is from mongo . i have to create a dataframe  using pyspark . We dont use  connectors between mongodb and pyspark

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8101649/python-dictionary-removing-u-chars

Comment: Go through this and read the data in json itself. It will create a df  right. Do a collect on it. Then, use .join() (not SQL joins) to join back.

Comment: from bson import json_util
with open("/XXXXX6/bi/XXXXX/XXXXX3/v0/test/bson.json", "rb") as f:
bson = f.read()
data= bson.replace('u\'','') – removal of Unicode 
data1 = data.replace('\n','') – removal of \n
json.dump(json_util.dumps(data), open("bson1.json", "w"))

Can you show me the output for this?

Comment: prazy : I faced hard time in resolving this unicode error . So i used pymongo and extracted data from it, created a dataframe using pandas  and converted it to spark dataframe and finally loaded in to hive table . thanks for your help .. i am all done ..:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use ensure_ascii=False in the json.dumps:

```
bson = f.read()
json.dumps(bson, ensure_ascii=False).encode('utf8')
```

This will avoid the unicode output. The encode function can be used to encode to your desired format. Most of the times you will be safe with 'utf8'

Comment: No i am still getting this unicode error . else u can guide me in replacing u as i am using teh line data= bson.replace('u\'','') – removal of Unicode, but this line removes the u along with the first single quotes . we should remove and replace it with a single quote

Comment: Then you need to join it. @ra

Comment: @Prazy Target is i need to load it in to a dataframe . what should i do with my json . becoz when i load my json i could find that my json is valid . buy spark is not allowing to create a dataframe . it shows corrupt records

Comment: I use the below command for loading it in to pyspark
 test=hiveContext.read.option("multiline","true").json(sc.wholeTextFiles('file:/xxx/xxxx.json').values())

Comment: @Raja hiveContext.read() will create a DataFrame. Can you paste the output in the question? When you type in test.

Comment: @prazy it is corrupt record.. that is the output

Comment: @Raja https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8101649/python-dictionary-removing-u-chars

Go through the answer given by Raymond Hettinger.

Comment: @prazy : issue is not resloved. followed all the steps to remove unicode . what ever i do i am getting the data with the  unicode  u